# local variable 'perimeter' referenced before assignment?

Tags: python, class, error-handling

I'm teaching myself how to do classes on Python and am stumped on this part. Here is the code:

```
import random

class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        length = random.randint(1,25)
        width = random.randint(25,50)

    def calc_area(self):

        area = length * width

        return area
    def calc_perimeter(self):

        perimeter = (length * 2) + (perimeter * 2)
        return perimeter

#main

length = random.randint(1,25)
width = random.randint(25,50)
rect = Rectangle(length,width)
area = float(rect.calc_area())
perimeter = float(rect.calc_perimeter())


print("The area of the rectangle is %.2f and the perimeter is %.2f " %(area,perimeter))
```

Every time I run the program it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/CS DRIVE/Sample Text for Python/buusheee.py", line 28, in <module>
    perimeter = float(rect.calc_perimeter())
  File "/Volumes/CS DRIVE/Sample Text for Python/buusheee.py", line 19, in calc_perimeter
    perimeter = (length * 2) + (perimeter * 2)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'perimeter' referenced before assignment
```

I'm not sure what the error is with "Perimeter" since I followed the same code format for getting the area and it doesn't give me any problems. The error only comes up when I include the perimeter. If you eliminate the perimeter and only leave the  area, it runs. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line fails , because you are trying to use `perimeter` in the right hand side, before it has been defined -

```
perimeter = (length * 2) + (perimeter * 2)
```

And I really do not think you wanted to use perimeter there. I believe you want to use `width` there instead (since that would be the correct formula for perimeter of a rectangle) , as -

```
perimeter = (length * 2) + (width * 2)
```

---

Also, currently when you access `length` or `width` , you are accessing the global variables, you should instead access `self.length` and `self.width` , so that you access that particular instance's length and width -

```
perimeter = (self.length * 2) + (self.width * 2)
```

Similar change to your `calc_area()` method as well.

Comment: Oh my god I'm an idiot. You're right. I have no idea how I didn't catch that. Thank you so much for catching that silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You should also be accessing the `width` and `height` properties of the `Rectangle` instance by using `self.width` and `self.height` in the methods. Consider:

```
import random

class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width

    def calc_area(self):

        area = self.length * self.width
        return area

    def calc_perimeter(self):

        perimeter = (self.length * 2) + (self.width * 2)
        return perimeter

#main

length = random.randint(1,25)
width = random.randint(25,50)
rect = Rectangle(length,width)
area = float(rect.calc_area())
perimeter = float(rect.calc_perimeter())

print("The area of the rectangle is %.2f and the perimeter is %.2f " %(area,perimeter))
```